# Why to cast pointer to double pointer in c?

Tags: c, class, oop, double-pointer

I am reading OOP in C, and there is this header:

```
#ifndef _NEW_H
#define _NEW_H

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

void *new (const void *type, ...);
void delete (void *item);

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    void *(*ctor)(void *self, va_list *app);
    void *(*dtor)(void *self);
    void *(*clone)(const void *self);
    int (*differ)(const void *self, const void *x);
} class_t;

inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)
{
    const class_t *class = _class;
    void *p = calloc(1, class->size);

    assert(p);
    *(const class_t **)p = class; //why would you cast to double pointer, when you immediately dereference it?

    if (class->ctor)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, _class);
        p = class->ctor(p, &args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    return p;
}

#endif //_NEW_H
```

Now I don't understand this expression:

```
*(const class_t **)p = class;
```

What does it mean `const class_t **` type? it is like an array of arrays? but if I want to have custom class (that is, not only pointer to the struct `class_t`, but more "public" methods), the overall class is not an array of types `class_t`. So Why would I cast a void pointer to double pointer and immediately dereference it? How should I understand it?

from the book about that statement:
`* (const struct Class **) p = class;`

> p points to the beginning of the new memory area for the object. We
> force a conversion of p which treats the beginning of the object as a
> pointer to a struct class_t and set the argument class as the value of
> this pointer.

Comment: Seeing `class` in C code is a sign you better strap in because it's going to be a wild ride.

Comment: @tadman but that is the point. I started with the notation I am learning OOP in c

Comment: Considering Objective-C and C++ already exist, not to mention other lesser-known experiments, I'm wondering *why*.

Comment: @tadman becuase for example kernel uses OOP principles

Comment: Which kernel? This code is academically interesting if only because it's quite peculiar, but I'm not sure what utility it actually has.

Comment: the "class" here is plain variable name, not compiler-syntax, so keep it calm. It is just C

Comment: Obviously. That casting on assignment honestly seems kind of pointless, C doesn't really care too much what you assign to `void*`, but maybe there's a reason for it that's not clear. I'd step through in a debugger to see what's going on there, but you'd need an example that exercises this code to find out more.

Comment: So double pointer dereference once back to pointer and then place class?  Add in varg black magic for fun where you store a va_list stack variable's address into class then let it go out of scope?  What could go wrong?  Hope that ctor deep copies.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan there is nothing wrong with it, but the question is not to *find the bug* but rather explanation of why to cast to double-pointer and the dereference. It is not the first time I see something similar. Just asking about the reason, or practicall usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `calloc()` is being used to allocate an array of 1 element of an unspecified "class" type, where the first member of that type is expected to be a `class_t*` pointer (thus `class->size` must be at least `sizeof(class_t*)`, but can be higher).  `calloc()` is likely being used instead of `malloc()` just so that any additional data members represented by `class->size` will be zero-initialized, otherwise an explicit `memset()` would be needed.

The weird cast+dereference is just so that the code can store the input `class` pointer directly into that 1st `class_t*` member of that allocated object.

An array can be accessed using a double-pointer.  Dereferencing such a pointer gives you the address of the 1st element in the array.  Which in this case happens to also be the same address as the `class_t*` member.

In OOP terms, the layout of an object in memory typically starts with a pointer to the object class's vtable, which contains a list of function pointers to the class's "virtual" methods.  When a class is "derived" from, descendants "override" virtual methods by simply setting the object's vtable pointer to a new list of function pointers.  This concept of OOP doesn't really exist in C, but it is fundamental to C++.  In C, it has to be implemented manually, which is what this code is doing.

Basically, the code is allocating this memory layout for the allocated object:

```
           ------------    --------------------
void *p -> | class_t* | -> | size_t size       |
           ------------    --------------------
           | ...      |    | void (*ctor)()   |
           ------------    --------------------
                           | void (*dtor)()   |
                           --------------------
                           | void (*clone)()  |
                           --------------------
                           | void (*differ)() |
                           --------------------
```

Another way to accomplish the same assignment would be to use a typedef for the "class" type for easier access, eg the original code is equivalent to this:

```c
typedef struct
{
    class_t *vtable;
    // other data members, if class->size > sizeof(class_t*) ...
} class_info_t;

inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)
{
    const class_t *class = _class;
    class_info_t *p = (class_info_t*) calloc(1, class->size);

    assert(p);
    p->vtable = class;
    // other data members are implicitly zeroed by calloc() ...

    ...
}
```

Without using any typedefs or casting at all, `memcpy()` can be used to accomplish the same thing, eg:

```c
inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)
{
    const class_t *class = _class;
    void *p = calloc(1, class->size);

    assert(p);
    memcpy(p, &class, sizeof(class));

    ...
}
```

Comment: but why it wasn directly `(class_t *)p = _class`, when the `p` is `void*` anyway, so I can cast it any pointer type I want. Why do I have to use double pointer to `class_t` and therefor at least once to dereference?

Comment: @milanHrabos Because it points to an object in memory, and the object has various fields, and the first of these fields is a pointer, namely the vtable pointer, and you want to initialise that pointer.

Comment: "*why it wasn directly `(class_t *)p = _class`*"" - because 1) that doesn't work, syntax-wise, and 2) that wouldn't accomplish the desired task of copying the *value* of `class` into the front of the allocated memory. I have updated my answer to explain this more.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean `const class_t ** type?`

It is a pointer to a pointer. It expresses that whatever it points to is actually another pointer. And that 2nd points to the concrete object of type, in this case, `class_t`

```
[type] ---> [2nd pointer] ---> [class_t object]
```

**Why `*(const class_t **)p = class;`?**

What this weird construction do is to place `class` where the "class_t object" is. Now, looking at how this `new` function is supposed to be used it is not that weird.

The `new` is a generic constructor of any custom type (struct). There is however a requirement on the **type** which is that the structure must include **pointer to the class_t** as a first member. This is to enable polymorphism and basically what C++ does under the hood with a pointer to v-table.

Now, if I would be to define a custom type I would do:

```
struct Foo {
    void *class_t;
    // whatever members I need for my type
};
```

**How to use it?**

Now, when the type is defined there is one more thing to do. Note that the `new` function as an argument takes a pointer `inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)` that is used as a foundation `const class_t *class = _class;` of the one that is being create. It would sort of mean that you need to pass something while you create something - so what is the point?

Well, there is the trick to define a const pointer to the **type** in it's header that can be used to construct objects of this type.

In the foo header:

```
struct Foo {
    void *class_t;
    // whatever members I need for my type
};

static const struct class_t _Foo = { 
sizeof (struct Foo), 
// and other functions such ad ctor, dtro, etc...
}; 

const void *Foo = &_Foo;
```

The above defines a custom type together with a matrix to create all of the objects of this type. It is important to note that it is of type `class_t` and that the size of the `Foo` is recorded.

Finally, new objects of Foo are created as follows:

```
void *f = new(Foo);
```

The `Foo` is however of type `class_t` but we want it to be `Foo`. The first element of the `Foo` struct is the pointer to `class_t` and so in order to create this relation the double pointer needs to be used inside of the `new`